# How to copy a text from java code in cygwin?

Tags: java

I need to get the value of selected item and to copy it from Java application in cygwin.

My problem is that I don't know how to copy a text from Java application in cygwin.

This is a portion of my code:

```
private void jComboBox1ActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {
    String cmmd = "moshell"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem()
    /*I need a help here :how to write this text (cmmd) in cygwin?*/ 
}
```

I'm debutant in programming.  Can someone help me to resolve this problem. Thank you.

Comment: Do you want to copy the value to the clipboard and be able paste into cygwin?

Comment: Yes, but where is the program that produces `moshell "selecteditem"` been executed?  Is it in a different environment other than cygwin or are you executing the original program within `cygwin`?  Would copying the value to the clipboard, which would allow you to paste the resulting into cygwin be acceptable?

Comment: I want to copy this:moshell "selecteditem" into cygwin not into clipoard.I want to see this text in the console when I select an item.

Comment: Okay, from what context are you running the application?  Are you running it from within the cygwin console?

Comment: You're trying to dump the command to the command prompt so you can run it from within cygwin aren't you

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, the same way you write any text to the console,

```
// I need a help here :how to write this text (cmmd) in cygwin?
String cmmd = "moshell"+jComboBox1.getSelectedItem();
System.out.println(cmmd);
```

Comment: This does not work.I not need to print the text (cmmd) in cygwin, but it does not work

Comment: @user3398735 Yes it does. Run java -jar myjar.jar in cygwin and it works just fine.

Comment: I have selected an item but I didn't see the text in the console.can you help me more?